# vb.net LinkedResource with a variable for the path/filename

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to reference an image location.  This works:

```
Dim r1img3 As New LinkedResource("\\raws01\nacha$\achSystemItems\emailImages\r1img3.jpg")
```

But I'm trying to make the path portion get pulled in as a preset variable and concat it with the filename but I can't get it to work.

I'm basically trying to do something like this:

```
Dim emailImages As String = CStr(Dts.Variables("emailImages").Value)
Dim r1img3 As New LinkedResource(emailImages + "r1img3.jpg")
```

Any help please?  Much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean you can't get it to work? What happens when you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't tell without knowing what `CStr(Dts.Variables("emailImages").Value)` produces. Give this a try, may be you are just overlooking a `\`.

```
Dim r1img3 As New LinkedResource(Path.Combine(emailImages,"r1img3.jpg"))
```